# React Router and keycloak Route Guarding is redirecting upon page refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, keycloak

I am using React Router v5, keycloak-js and @react-keycloak/web to implement route guarding and user authentication. The main idea is that the `SecuredPage` component is to be protected from unauthenticated users, wherein they should be redirected to `/login` if they are not yet logged in.

Here is how my app is set up:

App.js:

```js
const App = (props) => {
const keycloak = new Keycloak("/keycloak.json");

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <ReactKeycloakProvider authClient={keycloak}>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" exact>
            <Login />
          </Route>
          <RouteGuard path="/secured" exact component={SecuredPage} />
        </Switch>
      </ReactKeycloakProvider>
    </div>
  );
};
```

And the following is my RouteGuard component:

```js
const RouteGuard = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { keycloak } = useKeycloak();
  const isLoggedIn = keycloak.authenticated;

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => {
        if (isLoggedIn) {
          console.log("USER IS LOGGED IN, RENDERING COMPONENT");
          return <Component />;
        } else {
          console.log("USER NOT LOGGED IN, REDIRECT TO LOGIN");
          return (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/login",
                state: {
                  error: "You must login to continue.",
                  from: props.location.pathname,
                  redirected: true,
                },
              }}
            />
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

The app works great if I manually navigate to `/secured`, then I get redirected to keycloak's login page. The problem is, once I am already logged in and I go to `/secured` page, and from within that page, reload (F5), I get thrown into `/login` even though my keycloak session is still up. This doesn't happen if I navigate normally or when using the back and forward buttons of the browser. It only seems to happen on page reload or when I manually type into the URL bar.

I'm thinking maybe the RouteGuard component returns the **Redirect** before the **isLoggedIn** variable gets initialized during a page reload, but I can't figure out how I should make it so that the RouteGuard component's redirect waits to check the isLoggedIn variable?

Is there a better way on implementing Route Guards using React Router?